# Adding a legend to an histogram plot that has several stat_bin layers using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I need to draw a plot that contains several histograms with different bin size configurations. For this I'm using several stat_bin layers. The plot is ok, but I can't get how to add a legend that connects each histogram name with the filling color.

I have been trying several options but no one seems to work. Any idea how to do this?

Here is the code:

```
  hist.name.list <- list("H1", "H2", "H3")    
  returns.data.frame <- data.frame("H1" = runif(100, 4.0, 7.5), 
                                   "H2" = runif(100, 1.0, 5.0), 
                                   "H3" = runif(100, 6.0, 9.5))
  breaks.list <- list(seq(4, 7.5, 0.1),
                      seq(1, 5, 0.4),
                      seq(6, 9.5, 0.8))
  color <- c(1,2,3)

  library(ggplot2)
  m <- ggplot(returns.data.frame) + theme_bw()

  for (i in seq(1,3)) {    
    m <- m + stat_bin(
        aes_string(x = hist.name.list[[i]], 
                   y = "..count../sum(..count..)"),
        breaks = breaks.list[[i]],
        drop = FALSE, 
        right = TRUE, 
        col = color[i],
        fill = color[i],
        alpha = 0.2) 
  }
  print(m)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the stats point of view I'm not convinced that having different bin widths in one plot is a good idea (except for educational purposes).

Comment: I agree with you. But in my case I'm dealing with histograms in the frameworks of the Symbolic Data Analysis, where histograms with different bin size are sometimes compared or even combined (usually generating histograms with irregular bin sizes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have ggplot2 showing a guide (a legend) you need to map something to the respective scale. This is done in `aes` (or `aes_string` in this case).

```
color <- factor(color)
library(ggplot2)
m <- ggplot(returns.data.frame) + theme_bw()

for (i in seq(1,3)) {    
  m <- m + stat_bin(
    aes_string(x = hist.name.list[[i]], 
               y = "..count../sum(..count..)",
               color = paste0("color[", i, "]"),
               fill = paste0("color[", i, "]")),
    breaks = breaks.list[[i]],
    drop = FALSE, 
    right = TRUE, 
    alpha = 0.2) 
}

m  + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "group") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "group")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Yeah! That is exactly what I was looking for. In fact I tried to solve it in the way you did, but I didn't realize I was using aes_string, so using `fill = color[i]` was the problem :) Thanks for your help!